# Cassandra Pig example failing with wide row input enabled

Tags: cassandra, apache-pig

Using Cassandra 1.1.6, Pig 0.10.0 and Hadoop 1.1.0, I can successfully run the pig_cassandra example script in provided with cassandra in examples/pig.

But when I change

```
rows = LOAD 'cassandra://PigTest/SomeApp' USING CassandraStorage();
```

to:

```
rows = LOAD 'cassandra://PigTest/SomeApp?widerows=true' USING CassandraStorage();
```

I get the following error:

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 8, Size: 2
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:604)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:382)
    at org.apache.pig.data.DefaultTuple.get(DefaultTuple.java:156)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.physicalLayer.expressionOperators.POProject.processInputBag(POProject.java:579)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.physicalLayer.expressionOperators.POProject.getNext(POProject.java:248)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.physicalLayer.PhysicalOperator.getNext(PhysicalOperator.java:316)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.physicalLayer.relationalOperators.POForEach.processPlan(POForEach.java:332)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.physicalLayer.relationalOperators.POForEach.getNext(POForEach.java:284)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.physicalLayer.PhysicalOperator.processInput(PhysicalOperator.java:290)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.physicalLayer.relationalOperators.POForEach.getNext(POForEach.java:233)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.physicalLayer.PhysicalOperator.processInput(PhysicalOperator.java:290)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.physicalLayer.relationalOperators.POPreCombinerLocalRearrange.getNext(POPreCombinerLocalRearrange.java:126)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.physicalLayer.PhysicalOperator.processInput(PhysicalOperator.java:290)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.physicalLayer.relationalOperators.POForEach.getNext(POForEach.java:233)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.physicalLayer.PhysicalOperator.processInput(PhysicalOperator.java:290)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.physicalLayer.relationalOperators.POLocalRearrange.getNext(POLocalRearrange.java:256)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigGenericMapBase.runPipeline(PigGenericMapBase.java:271)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigGenericMapBase.map(PigGenericMapBase.java:266)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigGenericMapBase.map(PigGenericMapBase.java:64)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:144)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:764)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:370)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:212)
```

This happens  when running in both in local and mapreduce mode, or if I set PIG_WIDEROW_INPUT=true.

The following Pig Latin script will fail with the "widerows=true" parameter present.

```
rows = LOAD 'cassandra://PigTest/SomeApp?widerows=true' USING CassandraStorage();
cols = FOREACH rows GENERATE flatten(columns.name);
DUMP cols;
```

I can't seem to get beyond this, not read the static columns in the SomeApp column family when using wide row input. The same issue is present with other column families.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. It may be because of bugs in get_paged_slices which were fixed in later 1.1.x releases. The solution would be to upgrade Cassandra to <s>1.1.8</s> 1.1.9

See:

- [CASSANDRA-4919](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-4919): StorageProxy.getRangeSlice sometimes returns incorrect number of columns
- [CASSANDRA-4816](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-4816): Broken get_paged_slice
- [CASSANDRA-5098](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-5098): CassandraStorage doesn't decode name in widerow mode

Comment: Thanks Justen, the issue seems to persist with Cassandra 1.1.8.

Comment: @Rob - It seems there is another bug in 1.1.8 with CassandraStorage that may be fixed in 1.1.9 / 1.2.1.  [CASSANDRA-5098](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-5098).